# Rename files and sort them after creation date

Tags: python

I have a lot of files in a specific directory and I want to rename all files with the extension type .txt after the file creation date and add a counter prefix. By the way, I'm using python on windows.

Example:

Lets say I have the files `aaa.txt`, `bbb.txt`, and `ccc.txt`.

`aaa.txt` is the newest file and `ccc.txt` ist the oldest created file.

I want to rename the files that way:

```
999_aaa.txt, 998_bbb.txt, 997_ccc.txt ...
```

The counter should start with 999_newest file (I will never have more than 300 txt file).
Like you can see I just want to give the newest file the highest number (sorted by creation date).

How would you do this?

Comment: Actually I have a working code thats really ugly. Within a for loop I increased a counter but I was not able to start from 999.

Comment: So include your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this untested code:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

# get a list of all txt files
fnames = glob.glob("*.txt")
# sort according to time of last modification/creation (os-dependent)
# reverse: newer files first
fnames.sort(key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_ctime, reverse=True)
# rename files, choose pattern as you like
for i, fname in enumerate(fnames):
    shutil.move(fname, "%03d_%s" % (999-i, fname))
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html#glob.glob
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types